# Basic Cucumber test project - how to run java cucumber.api.cli.Main?

Tags: java, cucumber

I followed the instructions on https://cucumber.io/docs/guides/10-minute-tutorial/ and it works nicely with `mvn test`

But I want to manually execute using  `java cucumber.api.cli.Main`
which leads to `Error: Could not find or load main class cucumber.api.cli.Main`

How am I supposed to use cucumber manually outside mvn or IDE configuration which works?

Comment: Have u added the cucumber jars to the classpath? Can u add the full command u have used? Have a look at this https://cucumber.io/docs/cucumber/api/#from-the-command-line

Comment: @Grasshopper I dont think I have, cucumber docs do not say anything about that, only adding it in the project's pom file. How do I add it to the classpath?

Comment: Are you able to use this command to run cucumber tests from command line?

Answer (score 1):

**Without Overriding Cucumber Options :**

1. Open the command prompt and cd until the project root directory.
2. command prompt: mvn clean test
   Note: mvn test runs Cucumber Features using Cucumber’s JUnit Runner.

**Overriding Cucumber Options :**

At times, you would need to override the configurations specified in @CucumberOptions. If we want to override the configurations mentioned in the Runner, then we need to use following command:

**mvn clean test -Dcucumber.options="src/ressouces/features --tags @tag_name"**